# Diffimg c++ Image comparer Diffimg-2.2.0

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

H I have the source code of Diffimg-2.2.0 (Image comparision tool) and the compilation process return this error:

D:\C++\Diffimg-2.2.0-src\3rdparty\qtpropertybrowser\qtpropertybrowser.h:44: error: QtGui/QWidget: No such file or directory
 #include 
                         ^

Using: QT Creator 3.3.0 and Cmake 2.6 as compiler

Source code on SF:  http://sourceforge.net/projects/diffimg/files/

Somebody has modified this code yet?

Comment: Can you post the exact compiler output and some context around where the errors happened ?

Comment: Maybe this image help: http://awesomescreenshot.com/09545fhc83

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error means that you're compiling the code with the wrong version of Qt.

Most likely the project uses Qt4 and you're compiling with Qt5. They are not compatible.

Since you're on windows, you can find Qt 4.8 here : http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/install-win.html

Once you've installed Qt4 on your system, you can add it to QtCreator in Options->Compiler->Qt versions if it doesn't appear automatically.

[image: screenshot of Qt Versions tab]

Comment: Compilers tab is lacated in Build and run?

Comment: Have you installed Qt4? If so you should be able to add it in the Qt Versions tab : http://i.imgur.com/RhkZuSZ.jpg If you're having trouble with that, you should be able to use the QtCreator that comes with Qt4, maybe it's simpler like this on Windows.

Comment: hmm I can't find the link to download Qt4 file

Comment: Qt 4.8.5 MinGW : https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/4.8/4.8.5/qt-win-opensource-4.8.5-mingw.exe

Comment: I have found this: http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/download.qt-project.org/archive/qt/4.8/4.8.5/ thanks installing...

Comment: That's a problem with your computer, these links work just fine http://i.imgur.com/VioDF26.jpg :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68429/discussion-between-luis-and-tux3).